# What causes selectonemenu to display menu on top instead of below?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is easiest to explain with a picture. I apologize, but I don't have the reputation to post this internally.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gez9X.jpg

In summary: a primefaces selectonemenu is displaying the menu above the menu item that it is associated with. By above I mean on the y axis, and not in front or on top of as typically described. This works as expected if I use a core jsf selectonemenu though. What's weirder is that it does this only in firefox or IE, but not in chrome. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? It seems like it might be a css issue, but I don't know enough to determine this, and if so what a possible solution might be. I've included a full copy of the jsf below.
P.S.
This behavior persists without the extra line breaks and the panel grid. Without the line breaks the menu just falls off the top of the browser window.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</h:head>
<body>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
        <h:outputText value="Basic Usage: " />  
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{buttonBean.number}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>  
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in FireFox 22.0 nor Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your particular problem. However, it's known to do that when the viewport space in the bottom is too narrow.

[image]

Perhaps you've a problem in your browser's viewport, or there's more into the code, e.g. an CSS override.

Comment: Interestingly enough I was able to replicate this issue in primefaces 3.5, and 3.4.2, but 3.1 appears to display correct. I've compared the css code line by line in both chrome and firefox and they're identical as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tested with PrimeFaces 3.5 and Chrome 27. Other browsers work fine either. I've been using PrimeFaces since 3.0 and upgraded along 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 to 3.5 and I don't recall having seen this issue on our dropdownlists.